# Change event scheduler status in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, events, scheduler, mysql-event

I'm trying to stop only one event but the SQL below stops all events:

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
```

Or:

```sql
SET @@global.event_scheduler = OFF;
```

Or:

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 0;
```

Or:

```sql
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 0;
```

So, how can I stop only one event?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you mean that you have 5 *events* on *one* scheduler. Right?

Here is how you disable one event:

```
    ALTER EVENT myevent
    DISABLE;
```

Here is how you disable the entire scheduler (all events):

```
    SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
```

All this can be read at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html
How to disable one event is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-event.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the current global event status, this may be useful for you;

```
select @@global.event_scheduler;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider :

It is possible to set the Event Scheduler to DISABLED only at server startup. If event_scheduler is ON or OFF, you cannot set it to DISABLED at runtime. Also, if the Event Scheduler is set to DISABLED at startup, you cannot change the value of event_scheduler at runtime.
In such case to disable the event scheduler, use one of the following two methods:

- As a command-line option when starting the server:

  --event-scheduler=DISABLED
- In the server configuration file (my.cnf, or my.ini on Windows
  systems), include the line where it will be read by the server (for
  example, in a [mysqld] section):

  event_scheduler=DISABLED

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable [an event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20Events%20are%20tasks%20that,a%20specific%20date%20and%20time.) with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-event.html) explains `ALTER EVENT` statement and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057525/how-to-see-all-mysql-events-that-are-running-on-my-database/77435414#77435414) explains how to show only the events whose `STATUS` columns are `ENABLED` or `DISABLED`:

```sql
ALTER EVENT my_event ENABLE;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER EVENT my_event DISABLE;
```

And, you can enable or disable [event_scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler) itself with the SQL below so that all events run or don't run. *The SQL below doesn't change `STATUS` column of each event to `ENABLED` or `DISABLED` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158933/how-to-check-event-scheduler-status-in-mysql/77503837#77503837) explains how to check `event_scheduler`'s status:

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

```sql
SET @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler = ON;
```

```sql
SET @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler = 1;
```

Or:

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
```

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 0;
```

```sql
SET @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler = OFF;
```

```sql
SET @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler = 0;
```