# Show all MySQL events that are running on my database?

Tags: mysql, database, cron, job-scheduling, mysql-event

I have a MySQL database. I am running two MySQL EVENTs. I need to get rid of one. I don't remember it's name. What do I do?

Comment: what about `show processlist;`? Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

its simple  `SHOW EVENTS` lists all of the events in the current schema

To see events for a specific schema, use the FROM clause. For example, to see events for the test schema, use the following statement:

```
SHOW EVENTS FROM test;
```

Answer (score 21):

The `information_schema.EVENTS` table is where to start.

```
USE information_schema;

DESCRIBE EVENTS;
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| EVENT_CATALOG        | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| EVENT_SCHEMA         | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| EVENT_NAME           | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| DEFINER              | varchar(77)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| TIME_ZONE            | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| EVENT_BODY           | varchar(8)    | NO   |     |                     |       |
| EVENT_DEFINITION     | longtext      | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| EVENT_TYPE           | varchar(9)    | NO   |     |                     |       |
| EXECUTE_AT           | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| INTERVAL_VALUE       | varchar(256)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| INTERVAL_FIELD       | varchar(18)   | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| SQL_MODE             | varchar(8192) | NO   |     |                     |       |
| STARTS               | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| ENDS                 | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| STATUS               | varchar(18)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| ON_COMPLETION        | varchar(12)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| CREATED              | datetime      | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| LAST_ALTERED         | datetime      | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| LAST_EXECUTED        | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| EVENT_COMMENT        | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| ORIGINATOR           | bigint(10)    | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT | varchar(32)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| COLLATION_CONNECTION | varchar(32)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
| DATABASE_COLLATION   | varchar(32)   | NO   |     |                     |       |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+

SELECT EVENT_NAME FROM EVENTS WHERE EVENT_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

Comment: To show all events: `USE information_schema;
DESCRIBE EVENTS;
SELECT * FROM EVENTS;
`

Answer (score 16):

## Show events with more details

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.EVENTS
```

Comment: Best answer imho

Answer (score 4):

```
SHOW EVENTS\G
```

Which will bring you the list of all existing events. For **Show Events** Syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-events.html

Answer (score 3):

```
show events;
```

will show all the events .

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to view all Event Schedulers from all databases in MySQL.**

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.EVENTS;
```

**If you want to view all Event Schedulers from a specific database in MySQL.**

```
SHOW EVENTS FROM 'your_database_name';
```

**Event Scheduler Specific Query:**

```
SELECT EVENT_DEFINITION
FROM information_schema.EVENTS
WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'your_event_name';
```

**Database Specific Event Scheduler Query:**

```
SELECT EVENT_DEFINITION
FROM information_schema.EVENTS
WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'your_event_name'
AND EVENT_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show all events with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-events-table.html) explains `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS` table and I recommend to use [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) which can show them more clearly and the SQL below can show more details than [SHOW EVENTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-events.html) which I explain last:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS\G
```

And, you can show the events of `apple` database with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE EVENT_SCHEMA = 'apple';
```

And, you can show the events running currently with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE STATUS = 'ENABLED';
```

And, you can show the events not running currently with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE STATUS = 'DISABLED';
```

And, you can show the events of `apple` database selecting `apple` database with [USE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html#:%7E:text=The%20USE%20statement%20tells%20MySQL,or%20some%20object%20within%20it.&text=The%20database%20name%20must%20be%20specified%20on%20a%20single%20line.). *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-events.html) explains `SHOW EVENTS` and I recommend to use `\G` which can show them more clearly:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW EVENTS;
```

Or:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW EVENTS\G
```

Or:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW EVENTS FROM apple;
```

Or:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW EVENTS FROM apple\G
```

And, you can show the events running currently of `apple` database selecting `apple` database with `USE`:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW EVENTS WHERE STATUS = 'ENABLED';
```

And, you can show the events not running currently of `apple` database selecting `apple` database with `USE`:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW EVENTS WHERE STATUS = 'DISABLED';
```

And, you can show the events of `orange` database even if selecting `apple` database with `USE`:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW EVENTS FROM orange;
```

And, you can show the events of `apple` database not selecting any one of databases with `USE`:

```sql
SHOW EVENTS FROM apple;
```

Be careful, if you run the SQL below not selecting any one of databases with `USE`:

```sql
SHOW EVENTS;
```

Then, there is the error below:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected