# Finding when MySQL event last ran

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-event, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

I created an MySql event a few days ago. I don't think it has run. If I do `SHOW EVENTS` It started on `2015-09-07 00:00:00` and it has an interval of `WEEK`. Today is `2015-09-14` and it is well after midnight. It has a status of ENABLED. How do I know a) when it last ran, b) what it is supposed to do.

I created an SP which it was supposed to run. I tested this at the time but there is not sign that the SP has been run.

Is there any easy way to debug this? Or even a hard way?!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This information is available through `events` in INFORMATION_SCHEMA. [See](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-metadata.html) LAST_EXECUTED column:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events;
```

You can also use `SHOW CREATE EVENT yourevent` to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks, interestingly it hasn't been executed even though 7 days and 20 hours have passed.

Comment: I have figured it out I need to do SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON. It is turned off by default. Nice of it to tell me :>)

Comment: @RobSedgwick I am not positive, but you may want to look at your server config as well; so the next time it is restarted the event scheduler is not turned back off again.

Comment: You can use this for a more concise result SELECT EVENT_NAME, INTERVAL_VALUE, INTERVAL_FIELD, LAST_EXECUTED FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events;

Answer (score 0):

You can show all events in more detail than [SHOW EVENTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-events.html) with the SQL below, then `LAST_EXECUTED` column shows when they last ran. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-events-table.html) explains `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events` table and I recommend to use [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) which can show them more clearly and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057525/how-to-see-all-mysql-events-that-are-running-on-my-database/77435414#77435414) explains how to show events with `SHOW EVENTS`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events\G
```

And, you can show all the events running currently with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events WHERE STATUS = 'ENABLED';
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events WHERE STATUS = 'ENABLED'\G
```

And, you can show all the events not running currently with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events WHERE STATUS = 'DISABLED';
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events WHERE STATUS = 'DISABLED'\G
```