# How to check event scheduler status in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, events, scheduler, mysql-event

In MySQL, we can enable the event scheduler by following query:

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Similarly, to turn off the scheduler:

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
```

But, Is there any query/way to check the status of `event_scheduler` whether it's `ON` or `OFF`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [SHOW VARIABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-variables.html)

```
SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler'
```

Answer (score 7):

Use below command to see event status , you can choose any of them.

```
SELECT @@global.event_scheduler
or
SHOW variables WHERE variable_name ='event_scheduler'
```

To enable event temporarily ON or OFF

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

For permanent setup go to my.cnf or my.ini or inside /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf file and under [mysqld] set event_scheduler =ON or event_scheduler=OFF depending on your requirements.

[image: Event Scheduler ON event restart mysql]

Answer (score 3):

This should also work:

```
select @@global.event_scheduler = 'ON'
```

That is a little easier to use in a stored procedure, where you might want to know if it is ON before turning it on.  Note that I tested this on MySQL 5.7 after turning on Event_Scheduler either with ON or 1. In both cases, querying the variable returns 'ON'.

Also, note the quotes are used for querying, but not for setting the variable. A little mysql weirdness for you.

Answer (score 0):

With the SQL below, you can check `event_scheduler`'s status. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler) explains `event_scheduler` global varialbe:

```sql
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler; 
+--------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler |
+--------------------------+
| ON                       |
+--------------------------+
```

And with the SQL below, you can also check `event_scheduler`'s status. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html) explains `SHOW VARIABLES` statement:

```sql
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler';
+-----------------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME   | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+-----------------+----------------+
| event_scheduler | ON             |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

In addition, with the SQL below, you can also check if `event_scheduler` is `ON` or `OFF`. *If `event_scheduler` is `ON`, `event_scheduler` appears and if `event_scheduler` is `OFF`, `event_scheduler` doesn't appear and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html) explains `SHOW PROCESSLIST` statement:

```sql
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```