# Mysql query show if event scheduler is ON or OFF

Tags: mysql

On my website admin interface, I want to show to the admin if global Event Scheduler Status is ON or OFF. Is there a query for that? Did not found out Google-ing.

Comment: I'm sure there is a query for that but you have not given us any information to be able to help you. Where is this Event Scheduler Status stored? What have you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score -1):

SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler'

I have solved this. Duplicate in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158933/how-to-check-event-scheduler-status-mysql)