# MySQL event are not running as per scheduled

Tags: mysql

MySQL events are not running as scheduled but Successfully executing the insert statement outside the event. I would be very grateful if anyone could help with any idea. Code as below:

````
CREATE DEFINER=```christupw```@```%``` EVENT `ProcessAnalyticsEvent` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2020-05-20 13:59:59' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
    DO 
    INSERT INTO process_analytics (action_date, list_id, li_connections_sent, li_connections_accepted, li_replies, li_messages_sent, liconnection, lireply, em_sent, em_opened, em_clicks, em_replies, em_unsubs, emopen, emclick, emreply, emunsub)
    SELECT 
       date(Now())        AS action_date,
       T.list_id          AS list_id, 
       T.actid_1_status_1 AS li_connections_sent, 
       T.actid_2_status_1 AS li_connections_accepted, 
       T.actid_4_status_1 AS li_replies, 
       T.actid_3_status_1 AS li_messages_sent, 
       CAST(IF(T.actid_1_status_1 = 0, 0, T.actid_2_status_1 / T.actid_1_status_1) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS liconnection,
       CAST(IF(T.actid_1_status_1 = 0, 0, T.actid_4_status_1 / T.actid_1_status_1) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS lireply,
       T.actid_70_stage_2 AS em_sent, 
       T.actid_70_stage_3 AS em_opened, 
       T.actid_70_stage_4 AS em_clicks, 
       T.actid_70_stage_5 AS em_replies, 
       T.actid_70_stage_6 AS em_unsubs,
       CAST(IF(T.actid_70_stage_2 = 0, 0, T.actid_70_stage_3 / T.actid_70_stage_2) AS DECIMAL(10,4))   AS emopen, 
       CAST(IF(T.actid_70_stage_3 = 0, 0, T.actid_70_stage_4 / T.actid_70_stage_3) AS DECIMAL(10,4))   AS emclick, 
       CAST(IF(T.actid_70_stage_2 = 0, 0,  T.actid_70_stage_5 / T.actid_70_stage_2) AS DECIMAL(10,4))  AS emreply, 
       CAST(IF(T.actid_70_stage_2 = 0, 0,  T.actid_70_stage_6 / T.actid_70_stage_2) AS DECIMAL(10,4))  AS emunsub 
    FROM(
    SELECT pal.list_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 1  AND pal.activity_status = 1 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_1_status_1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 2  AND pal.activity_status = 1 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_2_status_1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 3  AND pal.activity_status = 1 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_3_status_1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 4  AND pal.activity_status = 1 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_4_status_1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 70 AND pal.stage_id = 2 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_70_stage_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 70 AND pal.stage_id = 3 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_70_stage_3,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 70 AND pal.stage_id = 4 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_70_stage_4, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 70 AND pal.stage_id = 5 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_70_stage_5, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ( pal.activity_id = 70 AND pal.stage_id = 6 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actid_70_stage_6 
    FROM process_activity_log pal
    LEFT JOIN processchart pc ON pal.process_id = pc.processid
    LEFT JOIN prospect_lists pl ON pal.list_id = pl.id
    WHERE pc.is_active=1 AND pl.is_active=1 AND date(pal.created_at)<=date(now())
    GROUP  BY pal.list_id) T
````

[image]

I just change the definer and then run SHOW PROCESSLIST:
[image]

Comment: Check the status of the event scheduler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158933/how-to-check-event-scheduler-status-mysql

Comment: event_scheduler ON

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7.30

Comment: when you run this .. do you see  EVENT Scheduler in the list..
mysql >  SHOW PROCESSLIST

Comment: Post edited, attached `SHOW PROCESSLIST`