# Scheduled Event in MySQL 8.0.31 not working

Tags: mysql

Two days ago I updated MySQL from 8.0.30 to 8.0.31, and since then none of my scheduled events are firing. The same script still works fine on 8.0.30

Anyone else having the same issue? Has something changed in the way events work? Nothing jumped out to me in the change logs.

My event is very simple:

```
CREATE EVENT tb1_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2022-10-01 06:00:00'
DO
UPDATE tb1
SET member_date = curdate();
```

Comment: Did you check the event scheduler status https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158933/how-to-check-event-scheduler-status-mysql

Comment: P.Salmon, yes I did, it’s ON.

Comment: Have you checked that schedule thread is listed in SHOW PROCESSLIST? Have you tried to drop and re-create event procedure?

Comment: Akina, Yes, the processlist has the event_scheduler and it’s status is “waiting for next activation”. I’ve tried re creating the trigger multiple times, and with different start dates / times. Everything works fine on 8.0.30, just not on 8.0.31

Comment: I look at bugs - nobody reports... maybe this is your local problem due to incorrect version upgrade?

Comment: Akina, how would I know if that’s the case? Sure seemed to upgrade normally, and without errors.